# How Do I Force A Specific Date Value into a Timestamp?

Tags: java, date, timestamp, timeofday

So I have a date value I had to convert to a timestamp in order to pass the value to a specific method. However, in order to finish the work, I've  been told the value of the timestamp's date has to be set to 1900-01-01.

So something like this

```
        Date startDate = timesDate.getStartDate(); 
        Timestamp startTime = new Timestamp(startDate.getTime());
```

But now I have to fix the date to that specific value, while keeping the time what it was.

EDIT - I have to pull data from a field that contains a string with a set time.

This will be a start time for one field and an end time for another. When this is saved the string needs to be converted into a timestamp, and the value of the timestamp need to be prefaced with 1900-01-01 alongside the time value.

CAN I ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION?

Comment: You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined innJSR 310.

Comment: `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: @BasilBourque  good point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start.  You should be using `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`.  This is just one way to do it.  There may be others that better suit your requirements.

```
// your epoch
LocalDate ld =  LocalDate.of(1900,1,1);
System.out.println(ld);

// now tag on the time
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalTime.of(2,3)); // 2:03
System.out.println(ldt);
```

Prints

```
1900-01-01
1900-01-01T02:03
```

To tag on the current time, just do this.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalTime.now());
System.out.println(ldt);
```

Prints

```
1900-01-01T16:06:50.190778200
```

You will need to check out the DateTimeFormatter to format the timestamp for your applicaton.  For more information on the latest time capabilities check out the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Starting with a legacy `java.util.Date` object, change the date while keeping the time-of-day as seen in UTC.

```
myJavaUtilDate                                 // Your `java.util.Date` object. Now legacy; avoid!
.toInstant()                                   // Convert fromlegacy class to modern class, `Instant`.
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )                    // Convert from basic building-block class `Instant` to the more flexible class `OffsetDateTime`. 
.with(                                         // Move from one date to another. 
    LocalDate.of( 1900 , Month.JANUARY , 1 )   // Specify date while keeping time-of-day, and keeping the same offset-from-UTC.
)                                              // Returns a second `OffsetDateTime` object, per immutable objects.
```

You can pass the resulting `OffsetDateTime` object to your database using JDBC 4.2 or later, with no need for `Timestamp` as explained below.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> I've been told the value of the timestamp's date has to be set to 1900-01-01.

I suspect you are confused about the oddity in the [deprecated constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int,int,int,int,int)) for `java.sql.Timestamp` that counts year from 1900. The Javadoc describes the first argument as: *`year` - the year minus 1900*.

That would be one of the many screwy design flaws found in the legacy date-time classes. Avoid these classes entirely. Use only date-time classes from the *java.time* packages.

## `Instant` instead of `java.util.Date`

If given a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to its replacement `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

If you must produce a `java.sql.Timestamp` object time interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( instant ) ;
```

You should no longer be using `Timestamp` to exchange values with a database. JDBC 4.2 and later requires support for some of the *java.time* classes including `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

You said:

> But now I have to fix the date to that specific value, while keeping the time what it was.

You lost me there. Edit your Question to clarify your problem and desired outcome. If you are referring the 1900 oddity discussed above, that is moot, a non-issue, if you follow my code using the *java.time* classes.

If you really want the date of January 1st 1900 while keeping the time of day found in the passed `java.util.Date`, you must first understand that the `Date` object represents a moment in UTC. So the time of day seen in UTC may be differ if viewing that same moment through another time zone.

I will continue assuming you want the time of day as seen in UTC. But you should edit your Question to clarify UTC versus some time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1900 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).with( ld ) ;
```

Comment: I mean I was literally told to force the date 1900-01-01 on the timestamp with the time as it was when I pull it.

Comment: @JackParker (a) What about time zone? (b) See my edits at top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

so, you want the date portion to be `1900-01-01` but the time portion to be whatever the time is from the `timesDate.getStartDate()`

Did you try using the [`Date.set*()` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to set the Year, Month, and Day to the correct values before constructing a new timestamp?

Of course, a lot of the `Date` methods are deprecated in favor of the `Calendar` methods, so a cleaner way might be to convert the `Date` to a `Calendar` object first ... or just live with the warnings for now.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, and I didn't do date.set for each, as I thought it would look sloppy, and thought I'd check if there was something I'm missing.

Comment: Anything else is even worse.  Create a date at `1900-01-01 00:00:00` and then run through `set*` methods to copy over each time part?  Works > elegant.  You can always make it more elegant later if you think of something better.